# sqlite - INSERT with UNIQUE constraint ends up inserting multiple records

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have following problem that I think stems from some mis-understanding of sqlite unique index CONFLICT resolution rules.

sqlite table:

```
CREATE TABLE `SEARCH` (
  `S`     TEXT,
  `SS`    TEXT,
  `HID`   INTEGER,
  `ISH`   BOOL,
  UNIQUE (`S`, `SS`, `HID`, `ISH`) ON CONFLICT IGNORE
)
```

Then I run 2 INSERT queries against it:

```
INSERT INTO SEARCH (S, SS, HID, ISH) VALUES (NULL, 'hello', 555, true);
INSERT INTO SEARCH (S, SS, HID, ISH) VALUES (NULL, 'hello', 555, true);
```

My expectation is there would be just one record, as second record would be "ignored" by sqlite because of "ON CONFLICT IGNORE" ignore rule...
Needless to say  - In real life I do see 2 records - why?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation:  https://sqlite.org/nulls.html.

Comment: As alluded to by Gordon; two `NULL`s are not considered to be equal, thus your two rows are not equal either.  Run the code again with `''` instead of `NULL` and it should behave as you expect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ahh. that's so unexpected. thanks -  its all clear now.